# How to configure this multi user logon scenario in Windows 10 pro?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I have a machine that runs Windows 10 pro. I've configured RDP with a max user limit of 3. I would like to achieve a login scenario where i have User A logged in physically using the machine for monitoring with Account A, and also the ability for a user B to login via RDP with Account B and perform tasks in his account. (so two separate logins, one for each user).

However this does not seem to work as I intended because whereas both accounts can be logged in at the same time and performing background tasks, only one user can be logged in actively on the machine. For example if user B connects via his RDP login, windows alerts that any other users currently using the device will be disconnected (but not logged out). This will disconnect the physical user (user A) from his own account. Is there a way for both to be using their own accounts actively at the same time on the machine?

Comment: This is a violation of the EULA and you won't get any assistance here for doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is Windows 10 Enterprise multi-session Edition. But it is only supported on Azure. Other Windows 10 editions do not support multiple interactive sessions.

To meet your requirements you would have to run this on Azure cloud or use server operating system on your hardware.

More information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-desktop/windows-10-multisession-faq#what-is-windows-10-enterprise-multi-session

Comment: I doubt the requestor wants or is a good fit for Workstation As A Server (WAAS) in Azure.

Comment: Maybe. But my point is that multiple sessions are not supported on Windows 10, unless it runs in Azure cloud